# using custom system.text.json convertor in masstransit

Tags: c#, json, serialization, masstransit, converters

I am trying to use my custom Json convertor in Masstransit But could not find any ways to add my JsonConverterFactory class.
Besides, I could not find any information In the documentation about serialization based on system.text.json
do you have any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

MassTransit currently (as of v7) does not use *System.Text.Json*, it uses Newtonsoft.Json. There are no plans underway to add support for it at this time.

If you were using JSON.net, you can add additional converters by configuring the JSON serializer.

```cs
cfg.ConfigureJsonSerializer(settings => settings.Converters.Add(...))
```

It's important to leave the existing converters or you may break existing functionality.

Comment: ^^ @OP see https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit section "Dependencies"

Comment: Since `System.Text.Json` is now the default (in v8), would you mind updating the answer?

Answer (score 2):

As of v8, `System.Text.Json` [is](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/upgrade-v6.html#version-8) the default Json serializer.

Configuring the serializer remains the same:

```cs
x.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
{
    // ...

    cfg.ConfigureJsonSerializerOptions(opts =>
    {
        opts.Converters.Add(YOUR_CUSTOM_CONVERTER);
        return opts;
    });                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I did not have enough time to write a new convertor based on newton. Therefore, I wrote this code. I know it is not a good way but it works for me.

```
    public class MessageConverter : JsonConverter
    {
    private readonly System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions Option = new() { Converters = { { new RmJsonConverterFactory() } } };
    private readonly Type[] Types;
    public MessageConverter()
    {
        Types = new Type[3];
        Types[0] = typeof(CreatePartyCommand);
        Types[1] = typeof(UpdatePartyCommand);
        Types[2] = typeof(DeletePartyCommand);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("data");
        writer.WriteValue(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, Option));
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        reader.Read();
        reader.Read();
        return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(reader.Value.ToString(), objectType, Option);
    }
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => Types.Any(x => x == objectType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using System.Text.Json You can alter the [MassTransit.Serialization.SystemTextJsonMessageSerializer] Type's [Options] static parameter (that is of the [JsonSerializerOptions] type) in your program startup:

> SystemTextJsonMessageSerializer.Options.Converters.Add(...

Note to Others: If you are running MassTransit in Newtonsoft.Json mode the [NewtonsoftJsonMessageSerializer] has separate static properties [DeserializerSettings] and [SerializerSettings] for customizing JsonSerializerSettings ;